# How to dock an application installed from terminal to the Launcher panel in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, application

Installed Linux and wanted to set up sublime text. Extracted it in the /opt/ folder and can launch it with "./". I "Lock it to Launcher" but after that I'm not able to launch the program locked.

Question: how do I lock so that I would be able to launch the program from the launcher?

Answer (score 1):

Create a .desktop file and move it to /usr/share/applications

How to do so, you'll find on [the Arch Linux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_Entries).